# How to set layout of any other item in RecyclerView invisible/gone when click current item

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

i need help.

I wanted to change button visibility in any other item inside recyclerview to dissapear, so other button except item that i selected become invisible ...

The trigger is when item get clicked/selected then any other item's button goes invisible/gone except the one i clicked... how do i do that? im using Kotlin btw.

Here is where i want to implement it inside "if (!b)" (if possible) in onBindViewHolder:

```
holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener {
           
            if (!b){
                b = true
                holder.addsLayout.isVisible = true

            } else {
                b = false
                holder.addsLayout.isVisible = false
            }
        }
```

Edit:

Here is my viewholder:

```
class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val itemTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitleRecordLocal)
        val itemDelete: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recordlocalDelete)
        val itemTranscribe: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.transcribelocalTxt)
        val mainLayout: RelativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recordlocalTitleDateLayout)
        val addsLayout: RelativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addsRecordLocalLayout)
}
```

I just updated my code earlier, so its not button anymore but layout, but i think its similar bcuz i just need to change the visibility.

1. itemDelete and itemTranscribe are buttons that i want to hide, and i put it in addsLayout.
2. mainLayout is the item where i need to click to be selected.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? What are expectations and what have you implemented so far? Attach some video/image of your view or something.

Comment: use to indexes -> one current selected position and other the previous selected index. when you click change the current previous and call notifyItemChangedAtPosition for those two poisitons. I am not sure if i understand your requirement clearly.

Comment: @krupaparekh for example when i click current item in recyclerview, any other item that i didn't click hiding their button...

Comment: @Raghunandan i know its difficult to explain.. for example if i click item number 5th, all other item that not 5th item hide their button or their button become invisible

Comment: @DiooB As I understand you want that if item 5 is selected then all other items should hide button and only item 5 should show button. Am i correct?

Comment: @krupaparekh correct... the trigger is when item selected/clicked...

Comment: @DiooB Can you provide the whole adapter code you implement and UI also?

Answer (score 2):

As per your code, I understand that you are passing any data class to the recycler view adapter of type suppose `myData`

Here is what you can do:

Take one boolean variable in your data class item, say `isSelected`, default value will be false.

Then whenever you get click of your `mainLayout`, change the value of that boolean.

Check condition according to that boolean and manage visibility according to that.

Also, best practice is you manage your clickevents in activity/fragment. So my suggestion is give callback of click of `mainLayout` to the activity/fragment and perform the next operations there only.

After that, in activity/fragment you need to make for loop and make `isSelected` false for all data except the one you selected.

For example in my case I have one music player recyclerview and need to change icon if one is being played then all others should be pause. So I need to change icon based on that condition. My data class contain one variable `isPlaying`.

In adapter:

```
// Inside view holder
if (data.isPlaying) {
    // set image of play
} else {
   // set image of pause
}
```

In on click, I have make one mutable live data and observe that in activity/fragment and get callback of click there.

Inside activity/fragment:

```
adapter.getListItems().forEach {
                        it.isPlaying = false
                    }
data.isPlaying = true
notifyDataSetChanged()
```